# Python sum and for loop taking too long

Tags: python-3.x, object, for-loop, sum, tuples

I am trying add cost values inside a tuple of objects. I have tried using a for loop and have also tried using sum as follows:

```
def cost_from_start(self, path):
    cost = -1
    for node in path:
        cost+=node.cost
    return cost
```

Tried using sum as well:

```
def cost_from_start(self, path):
    return sum(arc.cost for arc in path)
```

The tuple of objects look like this:

```
(Arc(label='no action', cost=0), Arc(label='SW', cost=1), Arc(label='SW', cost=1), Arc(label='W', cost=1))
```

All the cost values will be 1 for each object except for the first one.

However, both of these take too long for very large tuples. Is there a faster way to add up the cost values?

Answer (score 1):

Try using numpy to convert you tuples to an array and use sum on it. If your tuple is called `t`, then:

```
import numpy as np

the_sum = np.sum(np.array(t)[:, 1].astype(int))
```